# Are debug versions of (or symbol files for) the ATI/NVIDIA drivers available?

Tags: debugging, graphics, debug-symbols

I don't even care if they are true "debug" versions, all I really want are the symbol files so that my callstack isn't rendered invalid when I break into the debugger.

Comment: I was also trying to find pdb symbol files from nvidia, but according to Bruce Dawson at Valve, "NVIDIA, AMD, and Intel. None of them share symbols with the public" Source: http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/11/23/a-tale-of-two-call-stacks/

Comment: When you brake into debugger, how would it help you to see ati/nvidia stack calls? Also, which part of the driver are you referring to? If you want to brake in OpenGL, there are versions that will let you do so, try gDebugger. There are also debuggers from nVidia and ATI to help debug graphics issues.

Comment: AMD announced a public symbol server for their drivers a few days ago
http://gpuopen.com/amd-driver-symbol-server/ Nvidia doesn't have such option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMD now publishes symbols for their drivers:
http://gpuopen.com/amd-driver-symbol-server/

Answer (score 2):

NVIDIA published them as well ([announcement](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-driver-symbol-server)) under the following URL:

```
https://driver-symbols.nvidia.com/
```

It is just binaries, not PDBs of course.